# Restrict access to all USB ports to user account in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: usb, permissions, users

How  can I *restrict* all usb ports' access  permissions to user accounts in ubuntu 16.04 as a root user?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, I want to remove access of all USB ports for user account, I want know the commands and detailed procedure.

Comment: Alright, that should be easy enough. Is there a particular set of devices or device classes that you want to white-list, e. g. mice and keyboards? Otherwise you may be stuck without USB mouse and keyboard support.

Comment: Please tell me general procedure to do that

Comment: A long long time ago, I wrote a set of `udev` scripts that will automatically prevent and disable any connected USB drive to the system from being mounted or usable.  That works for USB sticks, but it works globally, not per user, and also affects authorized users as well.  (It should be possible to extend that to *all* USB devices but I'd be cautious with this since some system internal devices *look* like USB devices by the system, but are connected internally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subsystem in Ubuntu (and all modern Linux distributions) that handles what to do with devices that are added or removed is called "udev". It allows you to declare rules for what to with these devices.

If you place a rule file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` starting with `99-` it will be evaluated *after* all other rule files, *overriding* any settings made in them. This is what you want. Therefore:

1. Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-lockdown-usb.rules` (choose whatever you prefer if you don't like `lockdown-usb`) with the following content:

   ```
   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="09", ATTR{authorized_default}="0"
   ```

   This rule matches any "added" device belonging to the "usb" subsystem of the USB device class "09" (USB host devices) and sets the "authorized_default" attribute to 0 (meaning "false"). The effect of that attribute is to define a default for the attribute "authorized" of any subsequently discovered client USB devices connected to that host device. Unauthorized USB devices show up in the USB device listing yet remain dysfunctional.
2. To manually enable a connected USB device at a later point set its "authorized" value to 1 via sysfs, e. g.:

   ```
   echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/authorized
   ```

   (`2-1` is the USB device path assigned by the kernel in this example. Path names may become more complicated if USB hubs are involved. You can figure out the path of a specific device with the help of `lsusb -t`.)

   This will trigger all connection events like it normally would, e. g. storage devices show up in Nautilus and keyboards accept key input. The important thing here is that these sysfs files are normally writeable by *super-users only* which is what you want.

If you need to de-authorize specific devices or device types only or exclude specific devices or device types from the lock down you can refine the udev rules further to account for that.

<sup>Inspiration taken from [Plug and Prey: Malicious USB Devices](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/plug-and-prey-malicious-usb-devices#3.2_Locking_down_Linux_using_UDEV) but with some improvements.</sup>